# Similar Picker View for Swift

Tags: swift

Im new to software development. Im trying to create an app that shows cards as in a Picker view. Could someone please explain how does a Picker work under the hood?(I tried to arrange views in a zstack with a specified zindex for each one, from the first to the third, but I get lost with the gesture, I tried to change the zindex based on how long is the start gesture and the final gesture changing the zindex of each view, but it is not working)
Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: You're trying to build your own picker view? As in duplicate the behavior of a `UIPickerView`?  Might I suggest something less ambitious for a first effort?

Comment: @DuncanC Yes that's what Im trying to build.

Comment: I would suggest first using a UIPickerView set up to display images, and **then** try to implement your own replacement for it. Walk before you run, and run before you fly.

Comment: I've been developing on iOS for about 12 years now, and it would probably take me several days to duplicate the behavior of a picker view (including the 3D "rotating drum" animation effect. (Note that getting 3D animation effects like those used in an image picker is not documented well at all. It takes a lot of digging to figure out how to do it.)